# USQL Job failing due to exceeding the path length limit

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am running my jobs locally using the Local SDK. However, I get the following error message:

```
Error : 'System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

One of my colleagues was able to track down the error to the .ss file in the *catalog* folder inside DataRoot by running the project in a new directory in C:\. The path for the .ss file is

```
C:\HelloWorld\Main\Source\Data\Insights\NewProject\NewProject\USQLJobsForTesting.Tests\bin\Debug\DataRoot\_catalog_\database\d92bfaa5-dc7f-4131-abdc-22c50eb0d8c0\schema\f6cf4417-e2d8-4769-b633-4fb5dddcb066\table\aa136daf-9e86-4650-9cc3-119d607fb3b0\31a18033-099e-4c2a-aae3-75cf099b0fb1.ss
```

which exceeds the allowed limit of 260 characters. I cannot reduce the length of my project path because my organization follows a certain working directory format.

Is there any possible solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try using subst in CMD to workaround this problem by mapping a drive letter to the data root you want to use.

`subst X:  C:\PathToYourDataRoot`

And then in ADL Tools for Visual Studio set the DataRoot to X:

[image]

Comment: That might work for running it locally but not for automated tests. E.g. We have automated tests which are run with DataRoot referenced from output directory. This results in longer paths sometimes and we are only restricted to using output directory for test project